# Mailchimp API 3 Assign pending member to segment

Tags: php, api, mailchimp

On a project i'm working on i have a form which submits new users to a MailChimp list. The form has a couple of fields (firstname, lastname, email) en soms checkboxes with segments (tags) to choose from. These tags are used to segments user when sending emails.

Is it possible to assign a pending member to a segment (tag) via the API.

1) I first add a new member with the API `lists/{$list_id}/members`. This works without problem. The status of the member is set as `pending`. This is required so the member receives an opt in email to subscribe to the list.

2) Directly after this call i run another POST call to `/lists/{$this->list_id
}/segments/{$segment_id}/members` to assign this new (and pending) member to a segment (tag) in MailChimp/. While doing this MailChimp returns an error 'Email is not subscribed to the list'.

What would be the correct way to go for this? Any advice.